# Mercurial: Identify file name after rename

Tags: mercurial

Mercurial tracks the *contents* of a file throughout renames (`hg mv $OLD $NEW`), so that `hg annotate $NEW` also shows up the line-wise changes formerly made to `$OLD` with their original identification. That works fine.

BUT there seems no straightforward way to find out the name of the `$OLD` file, to which some given line has belonged within the ancestry of `$NEW`. `hg annot $NEW -r$REV` only works down to the `rename` changeset.

Of course the information is somehow accessible, e. g. by crawling through `hg log` (without `--follow`) and identifying the renames with some `hg log -r$RENAMEREV -g -p` (or by clicking through `hg serve`'s web interface).
But this “workflow” is not only annoying and error-prone, but [most importantly] it isn't non-interactive/scriptable.

My question: Is there a way to get/construct either

- some list of the file name history of `$NEW` (best with respective revision ranges), or
- the name of the file in which line `$LINE` was commited (some kind of filename option for `hg annot`)?

Ideas in either the `hg` CLI or Python/hglib appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either include the `{file_copies}` keyword in your `hg log` template:

```
$ hg init demo
$ cd demo
$ touch a
$ hg ci -Am 'file a'
adding a
$ hg mv a b
$ hg ci -Am 'moved to file b'
$ hg log -r . -T"{file_copies}\n"
b (a)
```

The built-in template `status` will include file copy info when you set the `--copies` flag:

```
$ hg log -r 1 -Tstatus --copies
changeset:   1:b37952faaddc
tag:         tip
user:        Martijn Pieters <mjpieters@fb.com>
date:        Sun Jul 31 16:07:04 2016 +0100
summary:     moved to file b
files:
A b
  a
R a
```

So file `b` was taken from `a`.

See `hg help template` for more things you can include in log output.