# print all versions of a file in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, cat

I would like to print all versions of a file, including renaming.

`hg cat -r rev file` can be used to print a single revision, and `hg log --template '{rev} ' -f file` can be used to print all revisions id of the file. Iterating over all revs is simple enough, but:

The problem is renaming. When file was called oldfile in a previous revision 123, `hg log` gives us the number 123, but `hg cat -r 123 file` does not work, because you need `hg cat -r 123 oldfile`. How can a script get the arguments needed for cat from the log?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685228/mercurial-identify-file-name-after-rename