# Find files copied in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I notice a mistake in file `original.txt`. How can I then find all files `copy.txt` that have ever been created via `hg copy original.txt copy.txt`?

I looked at [Mercurial revset](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets). The only time "copies" are mentioned there is:

> `"follow([file[, startrev]])"`
>       An alias for `"::."` (ancestors of the working directory's first parent). If `file` pattern is specified, the histories of files matching given pattern in the revision given by `startrev` are followed, including copies.

So apparently using something like `hg log -r "follow('copy.txt')"` I could find that it was copied *from* `original.txt`, but not the inverse (where `original.txt` was copied *to*).

How can I find the copied files?

Comment: JFYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685228/mercurial-identify-file-name-after-rename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dirty way**

(may give FP without corrections on mergesets when signal-string merged to new file)

If you have unique data (across **all files** in repo) in `original.txt` you can grep repo for this string like `hg grep -ldq "ID"`

**More natural way**

Because renaming file for changeset is "delete old file, add new", you can

- use "removes(pattern)" predicate in revset in form `removes(original.txt)`
- use special template `-T"{file_copies}\n"` for log

  `hg log -r "removes(original.txt)" -T"{file_copies}\n" original.txt`

revset can be reused as parametrized revsetalias (for *any* file), log with revset+template can be also converted to alias

**Addition**

For less-noise output for "just copy" changesets modified revset can be used (TBT!, I'm too lazy)

-r "! modifies(original.txt)"

Comment: This (second way) would only work for renames, but not for copies, right? (FP=False Positives?)

Comment: @Peter - yes, for "plaincopy" you can only remove revset in order to get results. FP is "False Positives", yes

Comment: I ended up with `hg log -T"{join(file_copies,'\n')}\n" -r first(file('original.txt')):: | grep original.txt`

Comment: @Peter - OK, while 1) I can't see reasons for revset 2) With slightly more complex template (I can do it) you can get the same results without piping to external grep

Comment: If there are many changesets before original.txt was created, searching them is very slow and unneeded. The `-r first(file('original.txt'))::` is my attempt to avoid that big slowdown. (It's still slow if there are many changesets after it was created, but I guess there's nothing that can be done about that, or is there?) Yes, a better template that avoids external grep might be interesting!

Comment: @Peter - it's ("many changesets before creating file") easy avoided by using filename as (last) parameter for "hg log" (see my draft of log) - "hg log FILENAME" output (and filter internally) **only** changesets, where FILENAME is affected in any form, you have to only add *additional* conditions. OK, I'll try to extend current version for pure-internal solution